# My JSON Array can only delete one Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I got some Problems with my delete function. The first delete is no problem, but if I try to delete or add another one after this it doesn't work. I think it have to be sth. with my array, but what ? I saw .live function, but it didn't worked.

```
      var data = [{
          title: "40 männlich Jungfrau sucht",
          director: "Judd Apatow",
          year: 2005,
          playTime: 116,
          fsk: 14
      }, {
          title: "Pulp Ficiton",
          director: "Quentin Tarantino",
          year: 1994,
          playTime: 148,
          fsk: 16
      }, {
          title: "Inglourious Basterds",
          director: "Quentin Tarantino",
          year: 2009,
          playTime: 148,
          fsk: 16
      }];

      $('button').click(function () {
          for (var e in data) {
              if (data[e].title == $(this).attr('value')) {
                  delete data[e];
              }
          }

          drawTable(data);
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *for* gives you an index, not the actual object, ie:

```
for (i in data) console.log(i); //  0, 1, 2
```

So you get the problem where, after the first deletion, the next index is no longer valid.  To get around this, you could iterating backwards:

```
for (var i = data.length-1 ; i>=0 ; i--) {
    if (data[i].title == $(this).attr('value')) {
        delete data[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of objects, don't iterate with a `for in` loop. Your `delete` is also deleting the entire array index, if you want that, use `splice`, if not, target the key:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].title == $(this).attr('value')) {
        data.splice(i, 1); //to delete whole array chunk
        delete data[i].title; //delete field
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should hold on to the index of the item you need to delete, break the loop, then delete. I used split. Don't delete directly in the loop.

Secondly you have a **spelling mistake** in pulp fiction if thats the one you were trying to delete.

This code works

```
  <button value="Pulp Fiction">Button</button>

  var data = [{
      title: "40 männlich Jungfrau sucht",
      director: "Judd Apatow",
      year: 2005,
      playTime: 116,
      fsk: 14
  }, {
      title: "Pulp Fiction",
      director: "Quentin Tarantino",
      year: 1994,
      playTime: 148,
      fsk: 16
  }, {
      title: "Inglourious Basterds",
      director: "Quentin Tarantino",
      year: 2009,
      playTime: 148,
      fsk: 16
  }];

  $('button').click(function () {
      var indexToDelete = 4;
      for (var e in data) {

          if (data[e].title.toString() == $(this).attr('value')) {
              indexToDelete = e;
              break;
          }
      }
      data.splice(indexToDelete,1);
      console.log(data);
  });
```